# WindowsError: exception: float invalid operation with shapely module v. 1.2.16 in Python 2.7 using PyScripter IDLE

Tags: python, error-handling, module, runtime-error, pyscripter

On Python 2.7 and windows 7 machine (64-bit). [Shapely module v. 1.2.16](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html)

**The error looks to be correlated with the use of [PyScripter IDE](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/)**. I tried the following code on 
Python shell and the code works perfectly

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

p1 = Polygon([(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1)])
p2 = Polygon([(2, 4), (4, 4), (4, 2), (2, 2), (2, 4)])
p3 = Polygon([(0, 3), (3, 3), (3, 0), (0, 0), (0, 3)])


>>> p1.intersects(p2)
False
>>> p1.intersection(p2).area
0.0

>>> p1.intersects(p3)
True
>>> p3.intersection(p1).area
1.0

>>> p3.intersects(p2)
True
>>> p3.intersection(p2).area
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 366, in intersection
    return geom_factory(self.impl['intersection'](self, other))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\shapely\topology.py", line 43, in __call__
    product = self.fn(this._geom, other._geom, *args)
WindowsError: exception: float invalid operation
```

Comment: Could not reproduce- I get `1.0`, with no exception (presumably because I am on a Mac)

Comment: @DavidRobinson, strange fact. I had try on different machine (window 8) and i didn't get the error. Looks only on this machine

Comment: That it's a `WindowsError` backs that up. Incidentally, might be a good idea to post a question along with the code (perhaps just mentioning the OS and shapely version etc- makes it easier to read).

Comment: On Python 2.7 and windows 7 machine. Shapely module v. 1.2.16

Comment: @DavidRobinson. I had tried on IDLE of Python 2.7 and not with PyScripter and i have not this error. Look related with the use of PyScripetr